# Is it possible to select a number from every given intervals without repetition in selections. Solution in LINEAR TIME

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, array-algorithms

I have been trying this question on hackerearth practice which requires below work done.

PROBLEM

Given an integer n which signifies a sequence of n numbers from {0,1,2,3,4,5.......n-2,n-1}

We are provided m ranges in form of (L,R) such that (0<=L<=n-1)(0<=R<=n-1)

if(L <= R) (L,R) signifies numbers {L,L+1,L+2,L+3.......R-1,R} from above sequence

else (L,R) signifies numbers {R,R+1,R+2,.......n-2,n-1} & {0,1,2,3....L-1,L} ie numbers wrap around

example

```
n = 5   ie {0,1,2,3,4}
(0,3) signifies {0,1,2,3}
(3,0) signifies {3,4,0}
(3,2) signifies {3,4,0,1,2}
```

Now we have to select ONE (only one) number from each range without repeating any selection. We have to tell is it possible to select one number from each(and every) range without repetition.

Example test case

```
n = 5// numbers {0,1,2,3,4}
// ranges  m in number //
0 0 ie {0}
1 2 ie {1,2}
2 3 ie {2,3}
4 4 ie {4}
4 0 ie {4,0}

 Answer is "NO" it's not possible.
```

Because we cannot select any number from range 4 0 because if we select 4 from it we could not be able to select from range 4 4 and if select 0 from it we would not be able to select from 0 0

My approaches -

1) it can be done in O(N*M) using recurrsion checking all possibilitie of selection from each range and side by side using hash map to record our selections.

2) I was trying it in order n or m ie linear order .Problem lack editorial explanation .Only a code is mentioned in the editorial without comments and explanation . I m not able to get the codelinear solution code by someone which passes all test cases and got accepted.

I am not able to understand the logic/algo used in the code and why is it working?

Please suggest ANY linear method and logic behind it because problem has these constraints

```
  1 <= N<= 10^9
  1 <= M <= 10^5
  0 <= L, R < N
```

which demands a linear or nlogn solution as i guess??

The code in the editorial can also be seen here http://ideone.com/5Xb6xw

Warning --After looking The code I found the code is using n and m interchangebly So i would like to mention the input format for the problem.

INPUT FORMAT

The first line contains test cases, tc, followed by two integers N,M- the first one depicting the number of countries on the globe, the second one depicting the number of ranges his girlfriend has given him. After which, the next M lines will have two integers describing the range, X and Y. If (X <= Y), then range covers countries [X,X+1... Y] else range covers [X,X+1,.... N-1,0,1..., Y].

Output Format

Print "YES" if it is possible to do so, print "NO", if it is not.

Answer (score 3):

There are two components to the editorial solution.

**Linear-time reduction to a problem on ordinary intervals**

Assume to avoid trivial cases that the number of input intervals is less than n.

The first is to reduce the problem to one where the intervals don't wrap around as follows. Given an interval [L, R], if L ≤ R, then emit two intervals [L, R] and [L + n, R + n]; if L > R, emit [L, R + n]. The easy direction of the reduction is showing that, if the original problem has a solution, then the reduced problem has a solution. For [L, R] with L ≤ R assigned a number k, assign k to [L, R] and k + n to [L + n, R + n]. For [L, R] with L > R, assign whichever of k, k + n belongs to [L, R + n]. Except for the dual assignment of k and k + n for intervals [L, R] and [L + n, R + n] respectively, each interval gets its own residue class mod n, so the assignments do not conflict.

Conversely, the hard direction of the reduction (if the original problem has no solution, then the reduced problem has no solution) is proved using [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem). By Hall's criterion, an unsolvable original problem has, for some k, a set of k input intervals whose union has size less than k. We argue first that there exists such a set of input intervals whose union is a (circular) interval (which by assumption isn't all of 0..n-1). Decompose the union into the set of maximal (circular) intervals that comprise it. Each input interval is contained in exactly one of these intervals. By an averaging argument, some maximal (circular) interval contains more input intervals than its size. We finish by "lifting" this counterexample to the reduced problem. Given the maximal (circular) interval [L*, R*], we lift it to the ordinary interval [L*, R*] if L* ≤ R*, or [L*, R* + n] if L* > R*. Do likewise with the circular intervals contained in this interval. It is tedious but straightforward to show that this lifted counterexample satisfies Hall's criterion, which implies that the reduced problem has no solution.

**O(m log m)-time solution for ordinary intervals**

This is a sweep-line algorithm. Sort the intervals by lower endpoint and scan them in that order. We imagine that the sweep line moves from lower endpoint to lower endpoint. Maintain the set of intervals that intersect the sweep line and have not been assigned a number, sorted by upper endpoint. When the sweep line is about to move, assign the numbers between the old and new positions to the intervals in the set, preferentially to the ones whose upper endpoint is the lowest. The correctness of this strategy should be clear: the intervals that could be assigned a number but are passed over have at least as many options (in the sense of being a superset) as the intervals that are assigned, so we never make a choice that we have cause to regret.